# Grunt watch for tasks instead for files?

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I`m new to Grunt and I saw a few tutorials about watch plugin. The example:

```
watch:{
 sass:{
  files: 'sass/*.scss',
  tasks: ['sass','cssmin']
 }
}
```

My question is why do I need to watch about another plungin like "sass" instead of watching the actual file(s) 'sass/*.scss'?

I don`t understand, it is not logical to watch a plugin/task, rather than a file.

Why I can`t call like this:

```
watch:{
      files: 'sass/*.scss',
      tasks: ['sass','cssmin']
    }
```

?

And what if I want to also watch about my js file? Do I need to put it also in the files of the sass tasks? It does not make sense to have js files into sass task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're by no means watching a plugin. Suppose you have another plugin less, which you want to work on a different set of files. How will you do it?

```
watch {
    sass: ...

    less: ...

    uglify: ...
}
```

Even if you put js files with sass (ignoring that it is horrible practice), when grunt calls sass on that file, nothing will happen.

As an example

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        jshint: {
            // ...
        },

        uglify: {
            // ...
        },

        sass: {
            // ...
        },

        foo: {
            // ...
        },

        watch: {
            javascript: {
                files: 'javascripts/*/**.js',
                tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify']
            },
            sass: {
                files: 'sass/*/**.scss',
                tasks: ['sass', 'foo']
            }
        }

    });

    // ...

};
```

There are different watchers for js, like uglify.

Comment: so I don`t need to specifiy the exact keyword for both, I mean it could be instead of sass, mySass? or instead of less, myLess?

Comment: @GigiIonel foo bar, whatever you want. The specification is slightly different. Though grunt will log these in output, so go for redability.

Comment: aaah, so now I understand, that was a little confusing...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not that you're "watching" that plugin, it's that you're watching a set of files and running tasks when the files changes. the `tasks` specification is where you specify what tasks you need. So in this case you would run the sass and cssmin tasks.

Comment: so you what you are saying is that the 'sass' keyword can be anything? I mean I could write like this watch:{keyword:{files:....}} ?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about ANYTHING (I've never tried that before), but I write my watch tasks with `all:` where you have `sass`.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` plugin watches files matching the pattern specified by `files` section. Whenever any of the matching files are changed, the tasks mentioned in `tasks` is executed.

For example, let us consider the watch task in your question

```
watch:{
    sass:{
        files: 'sass/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass','cssmin']
    }
}
```

Here, `sass` is just a name given to the operation. It can be anything; but since the operation compiles Saas files, the operation is named `saas`.

Whenever any `scss` file in `sass` directory is changed, the operation `saas` is triggered, executing the `saas` and `cssmin` tasks, which should be defined earlier.

References:

- [Getting Started - Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)